# Iteration over non-sequence of type `LineCurve`?

Tags: python, grasshopper

With the following code I get the error message below which I was not able to resolve using the [**documentation**](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/ironpython/index.html).

- `x` is an `integer`
- `ln` is a `Line`
- `degrees` is a `float`

Here is the code

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
a = []
for i in range(0, x + 1):           
    nl = rs.RotateObject(ln, rs.CurveEndPoint(ln), degrees * i, (0,0,1), True)
    a.append(nl)
```

I get the following message error:

> Runtime error (TypeErrorException): iteration over non-sequence of type LineCurve`

Traceback:

```
line 1076, in TransformObjects, "C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\rhinoscript\object.py"
  line 947, in RotateObjects, "C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\rhinoscript\object.py"
  line 924, in RotateObject, "C:\Users\**\AppData\Roaming\McNeel\Rhinoceros\5.0\Plug-ins\IronPython (814d908a-e25c-493d-97e9-ee3861957f49)\settings\lib\rhinoscript\object.py"
  line 7, in script
```

Comment: what is `x` in this snippet? And please post the full traceback.

Comment: The first parameter of `RotateObject` should be a string or Guid. Are you sure sending a `Line` object is fine?

Comment: You are right @Bibhas i need to convert my `line` into a string or GUID or find another way to do this...

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani No, you haven't. The full traceback is still missing...

Comment: @glglgl thanks question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Type Hint example]

[Bibhas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257944/bibhas) is right here. The `RotateObject` function only accepts a guid. If you change the type hint for the input then it will work as expected.
[image: The output]